# Run parallel test task using gradle

Tags: junit, gradle, build.gradle

We use JUnit as a test framework. We have many projects. We use gradle (version 1.12) as a build tool. To run the unit tests in parallel using gradle we use the below script in every project under test task.

```
maxParallelForks = Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()
```

Ex:

```
test {    
  maxParallelForks = Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()       
}
```

We also maintain the single gradle.properties file.

Is it possible to define **test.maxParallelForks = Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()** in gradle.properties file rather than defining it in each build.gradle file under test task?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`$rootDir/build.gradle`:

```
subprojects {
    tasks.withType(Test) {
        maxParallelForks = Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI gradle documentation suggests not using all available cores https://gradle.github.io/performance-guide/#_parallel_test_execution  See my answer below

Comment: The link above didn't work. Try https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:test_execution

Comment: Below is the error that I get. 

Error:(69, 0) Could not set unknown property 'maxParallelForks' for configuration container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfigurationContainer.
<a href="openFile:C:\enlistments\Android\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: is it possible to run tests in parallel in the same JVM?

Comment: @Capacytron Yes: `{ threadCount Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors() }` Infact that should be preferred over maxParallelForks as multhreading is more efficient that multiprocessing.

Answer (score 73):

The accepted answer above works but the Gradle documentation [here](https://guides.gradle.org/performance/#parallel_test_execution) suggests you use

```groovy
maxParallelForks = Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors().intdiv(2) ?: 1
```

I tried both and after testing both on a 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7 Mac Book Pro with 16GB RAM (4 cores with hyperthreading)

```groovy
test {
    maxParallelForks = Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()
}
```

and

```groovy
test {    
    maxParallelForks = Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors().intdiv(2) ?: 1      
}
```

The approach suggested by Gradle documentation produced faster response times for our unit test suite: 7 minutes vs. 8 minutes (compared to the original 13 minutes). In addition my Mac CPU didn't get pegged and the fan didn't kick off.

I assume there is either contention on a shared resource - even if it is only the machine one which we are running the unit tests.

Comment: 1 core with hyperthreading != 2 physical cores. so intDiv(2) limits you down to physical core count on a hyperthreaded cpu such as your i7. down side is on a 4 core non hyperthreaded machine you will end up with 2 cores unused for your test run.

Comment: True but just because cores are unused doesn't mean the tests will run any faster . . . . depending on what else is running on the machine

Comment: maxParallelForks = Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors().intdiv(2) ?: 1  almost made the running time half in my MackBook 6-Core i7

Comment: Forking is quite expensive: there's a heavy startup cost. This explains why limiting the number of parallel forks may sometimes actually make things faster. IMHO, it's much better to parallelize tests using threads instead of forked processes. See for example, https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.9.3/user-guide/#writing-tests-parallel-execution

Comment: If your unit tests take anything above say 15 seconds then the cost of the fork is negligible.

Answer (score 19):

For those of us using Gradle Kotlin DSL in a build.gralde.kts who find themselves here after a google search, I was able to get it to work this way:

```
tasks.test {
    maxParallelForks = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()
}
```

or

```
tasks.withType<Test> {
        maxParallelForks = (Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() / 2).takeIf { it > 0 } ?: 1
}
```

as I found [here](https://github.com/igorwojda/android-showcase/blob/master/build.gradle.kts)

edit: I ran into some issue as described [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/6453). This is (hopefully) my final form:

```
tasks.withType<Test> {
     systemProperties["junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled"] = true
     systemProperties["junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default"] = "concurrent" 
     maxParallelForks = (Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() / 2).takeIf { it > 0 } ?: 1
}
```

Answer (score 3):

kotlin gradle dsl

```kotlin
tasks.withType<Test> {
      maxParallelForks = (Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() / 2).coerceAtLeast(1).also {
        println("Setting maxParallelForks to $it")
      }
}
```