# Java Integration Tests running slow because of server starting separately for each class

Tags: java, junit, integration-testing, junit4

We have Spring Boot application and we have integration tests using JUnit 4 and  RestAssured Framework.

We have a lot of test related classes in our project.

Our integration tests take a long time to run locally, because each class bootstraps and brings the server - which runs the tests in the class and then terminates the server.

This happens for each class.

Bringing up the server and killing the server each time takes a lot of time - which makes running all the tests together really slow.

I would like the server to launch locally only once - and all tests to be run against it.

So basically my use case is when i am trying to run all tests at once.

Thanks in advance

Best Regards

Comment: Typically the Spring context only loads *once* unless it's explicitly dirtied, in which case it will be torn down and restarted.  Do you see any `@DirtiesContext` annotations in your tests?

Comment: Look into Maven, failsafe-plugin, and the proper lifecycles (three *integration-test).

Comment: Makoto i do not have any @ DirtiesContext in my code
@SiKing I see the failsafe-plugin is used, but what do you mean about proper lifecycles? (we are using 3 includes **/*IT.java, **/*IntegrationTest,java and **/*IntegrationTestSuite.java)

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference Bring up your server in pre-integration-test; run your tests in integration-test (default for failsafe-plugin); tear down your server in post-integration-test.

Comment: So from what i understand, failsafe-plugin brings the server in integration-test and kills the server in integration-test as well. How can i change this behavior?

Comment: Failsafe-plugin **only** runs your tests! **Something else** starts and stops your server - could be your test code (look for `@BeforeClass` annotation), could be another plugin, could be ... anything.

Answer (score 1):

Integration tests are typically slow. But to maintain test independence it is not always an option to move test preparation and cleaning outside of the test.

How about making the tests run in parallel? See [for Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23805915/run-parallel-test-task-using-gradle). This can be done in Maven as well I think.

Yes, that usually introduces a new set of troubles, like making sure that tests that run at the same time do not influence each other. Usually the ports used need to be test specific, usually providing 0 will imply: find a free port. During the test the actually used port can be retrieved.

The total speed up may be better this way, while maintaining testing independence.